# set input height to equal

Tags: html, css

I want to set the height of an input["text"] to equal to another input["submit"], but i do not understand what is going wrong. they move by some pixels.

This is my HTML code:

```
<input class="query" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search..."/> <input class="search" type="submit" value="Search" />
```

Css:

```
    .query
      {
          width: 310px;
          height: 28px;
          font-size: 20px;
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 2px;
      }
    .search
      {
          background-color: #ff7700;
          border-radius: 3px;
          color: #ffffff;
          border: 1px solid #ff7700;
          font-size: 15px;
          padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
          margin: 0px;
          font-weight: bold;
      }

    input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=password], select, textarea {
          -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
          -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
          -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
          -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
          outline: none;
          border: 1px solid #006699;
          border-radius: 3px;
      }

    input[type=text]:focus, input[type=email]:focus, input[type=password]:focus,   select:focus, textarea:focus {
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
          border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
          border-radius: 3px;
      }
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Proper indentation makes code much easier to read.

Comment: you have to take into account padding and border too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this would help you (Your Question is not clear, please provide HTML) -

Actually, both elements have save height. I don't think it's element height issue, it's vertical alignment issue(But not sure).

You can try `vertical-align: top;` Css property.

> **Note: It's might be give some different result in different-different scenario. You can see in Fiddle it's give correct output, but if you provide HTML it help us to understand your problem**

```
.search {
   background-color: #ff7700;
   border-radius: 3px;
   color: #ffffff;
   border: 1px solid #ff7700;
   font-size: 15px;
   padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
   margin: 0px;
   font-weight: bold;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rn6xv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but here might be what's going wrong:

I don't see `height: 28px;` under `.search` - that should make it the same height,

if you want all input fields to be the same height, add `height: 28px` under where you have `input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=password], select, text area`

You also need to take margin, padding and border into account

As james said - proper indentation makes it much easier to read - you might have picked up on the problems ;)

Hope this helps,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Set .query class's height to 30px

```
  .query
      {
          width: 310px;
          height: 30px;
          font-size: 20px;
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 2px;
      }
```

here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/9ZYCw/